# NonConcurrentGC Instead of ForegroundGC

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, clr

I'm looking over the outcome of some simple C# code that just adds 10 mil elements to an ArrayList (efficiency is not the point, I just needed something that triggers GCs).

.NET Framework 4.7.2 is used. GC is running in the default Concurrent Workstation mode, on a Windows 10 x64 OS.

BenchmarkDotNet (BDN) is used to profile the code and PerfView runs at the same time to collect GC info. I simply mention BDN since the induced GCs seen before and after the code runs are actually coming from it; it plays no other role in the problem at hand.

Looking over PerfView's GCStats data, and focusing only on one single run of the code, we get this output:

[image]

Let's take a closer look for what happens during the last background GC (`2B`), from within PerfView, by looking at the ETW events themselves:

[image]

As expected, the gen2 GC triggers both a gen0 (red highlight) and a gen1 GC (green highlight). Also, from Konrad Kokosa's book, "Pro .NET Memory Management": "*Foreground GCs are regular Non-Concurrent GCs, during which Background GC is temporarily suspended*"

In this context, **why isn't the gen0 GC - reported as NonConcurrentGC - actually marked as ForegroundGC, just as the gen1 GC is** ?

It's not a one-off thing either: the pattern of the BGC gen2 triggering one non-concurrent gen0 and a foreground gen1 GC is repeated.